# ASP.Net MVC - Passing data from one view to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I basically have two screens. The first screen taken username as input and generated a password.he password is valid only for thirty seconds. I need to redirect the user to the next screen as soon as the password is generated and  allow him to use that password on another screen. i am trying to populate the user model object with the password and passing it to the scecond view but my second view doesnt seem to get the data. Please find the code below

```
        int otpass;

        bool conversion = Int32.TryParse(Encryption.GetPassword(user), out otpass);
        if (conversion)
        {
            //Save user credentials.

            userModel.Login = user;
            userModel.Otp = otpass;
            string otp1 = otpass.ToString();
            userModel.OtpCrtDate = DateTime.Now;
            ViewData["user"] = userModel.Login;

            ViewData["password"] =  Convert.ToString(otpass) ;
            ViewData["status"] = "OTP: " + otpass + " remains active just 30 seconds from now.";

            return View("Access",userModel);
            //return View("UserLogin", userModel);
        }
```

Could someone tell me how to go about it ?

Comment: What isn't working?  You posted some code, but you're not showing or explaining what isn't working.

Comment: "and generated a password" - your view shouldn't be doing that. Your view should only be displaying information. Your controller should generate the password, then you can return any view you like via `return View("someViewName", viewModelWithPassword);`

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to persist the password in your favorite storage mechanism. You could use a SQL database for now, though something like Redis or another NoSQL backing would be better long term. You can store the username, the password, and a datetime representing the timeout. And when validating, you select for records with a timeout date greater than or equal to now + 30 seconds.

An alternative, but not great alternative, is to store the password in `TempData`. Just remember that data in `TempData` only persists to the next request. It looks like this workflow you have will require at least 3 requests (POST username, GET password entry form, POST password), so you'll need to retrieve/reset the password from `TempData` twice to persist it long enough to finish the workflow. Again, this is not a recommended route. It's dirty and prone to error, but if you insist on avoiding a database, it's really your only recourse.